# iOS Android login form

Tags: ajax, forms, mobile, authentication, hybrid

I want to make a hybrid app for iOS and Android by wrapping the MVC4 mobile website into WebView/UiWebView. However i want the login screen to be a native view.

How can I submit the username and password to my MVC4 controller where i can check them in the database and after authenticating to redirect the user on another page? Notice that i have implemented a login form on the MVC web site also.

Should i use a ajax call from the mobile app? Can you provide some code example/tutorial/video?

Answer (score 0):

That might be a problem because MVC is going to make some session cookies with tokens in it. So even if you were to get logged in using some kind of ajax call or setting headers and data and posting to the login process you still need to make sure that those tokens and cookies get set. And are useable by the Webviews.

I am not saying it can't be done just that it might be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Codersjunto. Can you provide me some link/post with a code from where I can see and get the idea?!